# Twitter invalid json when I try to login using twitter sdk

Tags: android, json, authentication, twitter

I'm trying to make a Twitter login on my app, but I have the same error all the times

I search some solutions on stackoverflow but no one helps me... I post my code below:

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LoginButton loginButtonFacebook;

TwitterLoginButton loginButtonTwitter;

PrefUtil prefUtil;

TextView txtEmailFacebook, txtUserNameTwitter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Twitter.initialize(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtUserNameTwitter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUserNameTwitter);

    loginButtonTwitter = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button_twitter);
    loginButtonTwitter.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
            Log.e("result", "result " + result);
            TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient();
            AccountService accountService = twitterApiClient.getAccountService();
            Call<User> call = accountService.verifyCredentials(true, true, true);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User> result) {
                    //here we go User details
                    Log.e("result", "result user " + result);
                    String imageUrl = result.data.profileImageUrl;
                    String email = result.data.email;
                    String userName = result.data.name;
                    txtUserNameTwitter.setText(userName);
                }
                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Twitter login attempt failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // Do something on failure
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });       
}
}
```

My strings.xml file:

```
 <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
 <string name="app_name">AppsLogin</string>
 <string name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_KEY">XXXXXXX</string>
 <string name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_SECRET">XXXXXX</string>
 </resources>
```

My bouild.gradle (Module:app) dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.0'
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.1.0'
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.1.0'
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.1.0'
}
```

My build.gradle (Project: AppsLogin):

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I click on Twitter button, it gives me this exception:

```
E/Twitter: Invalid json: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <hash>
         <error>Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'</error>
         <request>/oauth/request_token</request>
       </hash>
```

Comment: Fill up the "Callback URL" field in your Twitter settings dev account. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21430461/3111083

Comment: but... what I put on that field? I mean... I have no web

Comment: Read the 4th comment in that answer. You can put anything there.

Comment: i put placeholder.com and it said to me: Error
The client application failed validation: Not a valid callback URL format.

Comment: i also put https://www.placeholder.com and it said the same, any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just wait it out for some time. Probably it will take some time for the change to get reflected.

Comment: but it doesn't do anything... I mean, I put placeholder.com and when I click to "update settings" it said that the URL is wrong, so it doesn't do anything, no?

Comment: Oh so you mean they are not accepting that URL?. In that case I don't know what is the issue.

Comment: i solve it! i'm going to try your solution, wait, please! haha

Comment: I have now this error... : E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(104)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver
E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

          [ 02-28 08:53:57.464 14486:14557 D/         ]
          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8ac7d780, tid 14557

Comment: I put my email and my password and I think it makes the login correctly, but when I try to write the username on my screen, is empty all the time, any ideas?

Comment: I think that issue is related to chrome.  Like this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=662040. Are you using Chrome for loading the login page?

Comment: I don't know, when I click on login with twitter, it shows me another window, but in the same app... so... this error doesn't matter? why I don't show the user o the email instead?

Comment: What you mean by enter the username?. Can you check the text color?.

Comment: on the .setCallback, posted on my question, I have a method that gets the email, the username and the image of the twitter user that is logged in. but on my layout I have my label empty, with no information. The text color is correct, my layout is white and my label text color is black. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I fix it! thanks a lot, it works perfectly!